# pandas append each element of list as new row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with columns `first`. I have many lists, and I want each element of the list to be added as a new row.

for example if I have a DataFrame with a column `first`, and I have multiple lists, such that each element of each list, I want as a new row.
So If the lists are `[1,2,3]` and `[4,5,6]`, my dataframe will have 6 rows.

the desired output is:

```
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
4    5
5    6
Name: first, dtype: int64
```

I tried:

```
table = pd.DataFrame(columns=['first', 'second'])
my_list = [1,2,3]
my_list2 = [4,5,6]
table['first'] = table['first'].append(pd.Series(my_list))
table['first'] = table['first'].append(pd.Series(my_list2))
```

But I get `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`.

Comment: What would be in column `second` ?

Comment: `pd.Series(my_list+my_list2)
`